# Update table with result of query without deleting and inserting the same row?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a table `foo`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Now, in a PL/SQL procedure, I want to change the list of values for a specific value for `bar` so that it contains exactly those returned from a rather complicated select query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    x bar,
    regexp_substr(y,'[^ ]+', 1, level) value
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(y, '[^ ]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
) WHERE TRIM(value) IS NOT NULL;
```

This means I have to (1) delete all rows not returned by that query, and (2) insert all rows from that query that are not already in `foo`. So for instance if `foo` contains this,

```
1   A
2   A
2   B
2   C
```

the variable `x` is `2` and the query above returns this (as `y` is `C D`)

```
2   C
2   D
```

I would like to end up with a table `foo` like this:

```
1   A
2   C
2   D
```

Currently I do this by first deleting all rows where `bar = x` and then inserting all the rows from the query:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE bar = x;
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT * FROM /* the full query edited out for compactness */;
```

The problem is that this messes up my revision control system since I often delete rows and then directly afterwards insert the exact same row again. Is there any way to do this *without deleting the rows that will be inserted again*? I would prefer to only type the query once, since it is rather long.

Comment: Hi, have you tried a cursor?

Comment: No. Not sure how I would set it up. Not new to SQL, but quite new to PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

what about inserting/deleting the difference between foo and new values of foo?

```
delete foo ff
 where exists(with c_query as ( 
               -- result of your complex query
               select 2 as bar, 'C' as value
                 from dual
               union all
               select 2 as bar, 'D' as value from dual)
              -- delete foo not in c_query
              (select f.bar, f.value
                 from foo f
                where f.bar = (select distinct bar from c_query)
                  and ff.bar = f.bar
                  and ff.value = f.value
               minus
               select d.bar, d.value from c_query d));

insert into foo
  with c_query as
   ( -- result of your complex query
    select 2 as bar, 'C' as value
      from dual
    union all
    select 2 as bar, 'D' as value from dual)
  -- insert c_query data not in foo    
   (select d.bar, d.value
      from c_query d
    minus
    select f.bar, f.value from foo f);
```

Comment: Thanks for an interesting solution! It does require the repetition of the query, but on the other hand it is quite straight forward.

Comment: You could remove code repetition by moving the query to a view. You could reduce repetition of the execution by running the query and stuffing the results in a temporary table or PL/SQL collection.